# How can the volume between two cylinders and a plane be equal to $0$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, volume, multiple-integral

I am studying integration in polar coordinates using [this](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TICylindricalCoords.aspx) textbook material:

> Evaluate region between two cylinders $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=4$ and between $z=x+2$ and $xy$-plane.

And they say that the answer is $0$. The formula used is this:

$$\iiint\limits_{E}{{f\left( {x,y,z} \right)\,dV}} = \int_{{\,\alpha }}^{{\,\beta }}{{\int_{{{h_1}\left( \theta  \right)}}^{{{h_2}\left( \theta  \right)}}{{\int_{{{u_1}\left( {r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta } \right)}}^{{{u_2}\left( {r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta } \right)}}{{r\,f\left( {r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta ,z} \right)\,dz}}\,dr}}\,d\theta }}$$

Although what is $f\left(r \sin\theta ,r \cos \theta ,z\right)$? I believe for cylinders it's just $rdzdrd\theta$.

Anyhow, here's my solution that shows

$$\int _0^{2pi}\:\int _1^2\:\int _0^{r\cos\theta +2}\:rdzdrd\theta = 6\pi $$

I've no idea if this is right, but surely it's not $0$?

[image]

Comment: The problem comes from physics (calculating 1st moments of mass), not from geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it *is* $0$. What is being evaluated here is$$\iiint_E\color{red}y\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz,\tag1$$not the *volume* of $E$ (which is indeed greater than $0$). Note that $(x,y,z)\in E\iff(x,-y,z)\in E$; it follows from this that $(1)$ is indeed equal to $0$.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: Don't you know the meaning of integral of a function in a certain region?

Comment: It doesn't make any geometrical sense whatsoever to me.

Comment: What about the fact that $\int_{-1}^1x\,\mathrm dx=0$? It's similar.

Comment: Ah ok, so they wanted to know the difference between the north and south hemispheres.

Comment: There are no hemispheres in this problem. And I think that all they wanted was to compute an integral.

Comment: @Anonymous After normalization, it means the $y$-component of the *center of mass* of the solid being studied.  Why worry about geometry when you can worry about mechanics?